# Cannot import module from RxSwift in Carthage dependency manager iOS

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, carthage

Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1

[image]

Comment: Did you try to build project first?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I just need to run command line below, in order to compile with the correct version swift.

> carthage update --platform iOS